# Specifying a certain group in Django

Tags: python, html, django, python-3.x, class

I know this is probably a basic question for anyone who codes python regularly but I am new to python and have a pretty basic question.

Basically I have users within my site, and each user is specified a certain role.... On my home page I want a message that lists who the admins are...

I know how to create the message itself but I do not know how to pull only the admins out from a group of people with mixed roles..

```
class UserInfo(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    SERVER_ROLE = (
        ('creator', 'CREATOR'),
        ('admin', 'ADMIN'),
        ('moderator', 'MODERATOR'),
        ('normie', 'NORMIE'),
    )
    role = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=SERVER_ROLE, default='normie')
```

That is basically the code that I have for my basis.

I have tried to look at other peoples answers but i genuinely dont understand what they are saying...

Thank you!

```
My views.py is

from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import UserInfo


def admins(request):
    admins = UserInfo.objects.filter(role='admin')
    context = {'admins':admins}
    return render(request, 'userData/user.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve specific users with filters in django. [You can read the docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/). In your case if you only want the admins, in your views you can have

```
def Admins(request):
    admins = UserInfo.objects.filter(role='admin')
    context = {'admins':admins}
    return render(request, 'template.html', context)
```

which returns all the objects that meet that criteria. You can then display them in your message.

Then in your template you can render them like

```
{% for admin in admins %}
     <p>{{ admin.first_name }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: so when I did that, it returned:
<QuerySet [<UserInfo: UserInfo object (2)>]>

Comment: Right so that looks like you have two admins, so you can just push those to your template in a context dictionary.

Comment: So in order to get the names to display rather than the actual query set command itself, I have to create a dictionary?

Comment: If you want to pass any data from your views to your templates yes you have to create a context dictionary. If you want to see the names in your views you can loop through the objects and print(admin.first_name) and so on. I suggest reading though the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial03/)

Comment: Tutorial just confused me further it doesnt explain anything really, it just gives you the code.. Ill just go to youtube. Thanks though for the first part I just need to figure out how to create the dictionary

Comment: I edited my answer to try and give some more help. Good luck

Comment: Thanks man, now all I get is a code in unreachable error... I don't understadn why... the error is around where you define admins....

Comment: nothing changed in my code on the site... now the query is gone completely and the area where the admin name should be is just blank

Comment: Can you post your views.py?

Comment: Cool can you post the template too and the error message you are getting?

Comment: Dude okay. First of let me say I am a retard. I left my template name as template.html and I also didnt define the new url. Your code was absolutely fine and I feel so dumb... It is all fixed now and you are a legend.

Comment: Ha nice I'm glad to help. You can accept my answer to make me feel good too